# Running multiple non-blocking services at once with single maven command

Tags: maven

I have multiple plugins in my pom.xml that function as long running services.

- `mvn plovr:serve  # run a plovr server on port 9810`
- `mvn serve:serve  # run a jetty server on port 9000`
- `mvn sass:watch   # watch sass stylesheets and rebuild on change.`
- etc

The developer would need to run all of them at once to get a working environment.

What is the best way to run them all at once with one, easy to use command? Pressing CTR-C should kill all of them. I was hoping for a maven plugin that will run each command in its own thread.

Comment: You should bind them to the integration test phase which is controlled by a proflle. This will allow you to do things like this `mvn -Prun-servers verfiy` cause i assume you are trying to run a kind of test (unit / integration tests)..

Comment: No, this is not for testing. Each of those commands starts a service that we use to ease development. The sass:watch will re-compile .scss files when edited, and so forth. And each of these services can only be stopped with ctrl-c. So addign them to the integration-test phase, means the first one will run and block the rest.

Comment: Than you should take a look http://mojo.codehaus.org/mrm-maven-plugin/ which is service which is started during the test and does not block the rest. It has to be stopped during the phases. The problem i see that those plugins do not support the non blocking mode.